# Are Genetic Programming runtimes faster on QCs than on classical computers?

Tags: speedup, applications

If this isn't known, would they theoretically be? I'm particularly interested in knowing whether a QC would be faster at evaluating the fitness function of the possible solutions than a classical machine

Comment: I think it depends on the fitness function calculation algorithm. But in the case of most genetical optimization it is not particularly complex. I think it could help more, how to find better pairs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are [quantum algorithms for genetic programming](https://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0403003) which would theoretically have advantages over the corresponding classical genetic programming algorithms *but* you would need a full-fledged quantum computer with more qubits than any quantum computer we currently have, in order to observe such an advantage.